# getting directions and navigation for android

Tags: android, google-maps

how to use google-maps on API2 to get navigation to specified place
i've add a search tab to get places
but can't make navigation to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the following code in my application and it runs fine.

Here,

**saddr = source address(lat,lng)**

**daddr = destination address(lat,lng)**

Note that you can also pass  Address string in stead of lat/lng.

```
public void showDirections(View view) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr="+ latitude + "," + longitude + "&daddr=" + latitude + "," + longitude));
        intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Hope this will help...