# about function "get directions" in Google map android

Tags: android, google-maps, canvas

I'm doing app Google Map android. 
I want do function "get directions","suggested routes" and "Driving direction" in map .
But I don't know How do i need?

Answer (score 0):

So you want Directions from one Point to Another point right. I have developed it in my application using Google Maps Web Service and you can find the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760183/getting-directions-and-navigation-for-android/9760486#9760486).

Hope this will help you.